# Remember which DataGridview was last selected

Tags: button, select, datagridview, combobox, copy

I have two Datagridviews in one Form, one for regular orders and the other for topics in clarification.

With a Combobox i change the value from Datagridview1 column ["Status"] to "Clarification"

With a button, i save the changes in a Datatable.

After click the button, the row from Datagridview1 with Status "clarification" are copied in the datagridview2 and removed from datagridview1. (So far so good, everything is working)

**Now the Problem:**
If i want to run this procedure vice versa, for example a topic from Datagridview 2 is no longer in clarification and i change the Value in datagridview2 Column ["Status"] with the **same **combobox to "Open" i want the row copied to datagridview1 and removed from datagridview2.

Now when im push the button it's always a row from Datagridview1 selected and not from Datagridview2.

**For my understanding i need to remembering before i push the button which Datagridview was last selected**

And here my coding talent find a end

In which way i can solve this Problem?

I hope i described my problem well enough for you guys.

Thanks in advance for you high quality answers and solutions

Best Regards
Tom

I searching for solution since a couple of days but i didn't find any similar cases.